# Inserting/Updating date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

I'm new to php and I self-taught myself, since I need to. Now, I'm having trouble inserting the date into the database. How do I insert the date correctly into the database? I checked my database but the date field has only zeros on it. I would appreciate if someone could help me fix my problem.  Here's my code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){                                                            
   $fn=$_POST['firstname'];
   $mi=$_POST['mi'];
   $ln=$_POST['lastname'];
   $dn=$_POST['nname'];
   $age=$_POST['age'];
   $bio=$_POST['about'];
   $bday=$_POST['date'];
   $gnd=$_POST['gender'];
   $loct=$_POST['loc'];
   $query = mysql_query("UPDATE user 
                         SET firstname='$fn', 
                             minitial='$mi', 
                             displayName='$dn', 
                             age='$age', 
                             lastname='$ln', 
                             bio='$bio', 
                             location='$loct', 
                             birthdate='$bday' 
                         WHERE username='$user'");
}
?>
```

Comment: Convert date into Y-m-d format and store in database.

Comment: so What is the question?

Comment: First of all don't do queries like that. Use statement preparation and binding using [PDO prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: **WARNING:** You're using a deprecated database API. Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and binding your parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
$fn=$_POST['firstname'];
$mi=$_POST['mi'];
$ln=$_POST['lastname'];
$dn=$_POST['nname'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$bio=$_POST['about'];
$bday=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']) );
$gnd=$_POST['gender'];
$loct=$_POST['loc'];
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET firstname='$fn', minitial='$mi', displayName='$dn', age='$age', lastname='$ln', bio='$bio', location='$loct', birthdate='$bday' WHERE username='$user'");
```

`mysql_query` got deprecated as of `PHP5.5` so you must avoid using it and direct queries. For real world application and live project you must use `PDO` (PHP data object) to avoid `sql injection`.

Comment: Don't do that if you want to avoid SQL injection ! Use PDO prepared statements or at least escape all your variables for insert

Comment: I agree with you, but questioner this line `I'm a new to php and I self-taught myself` made me to answer it this way

Comment: @yiiframe horrible excuse. Always teach and preach the better ways. It's easier to learn a better way to start with than get out of a bad habit.

Comment: @yiiframe you should at least mention that it is a bad practice !

Comment: @SimonGuichard yes you are right. I updated my answer. I am new on stack overflow so I am not good in writing better answers like here I should guided the questioner to avoid direct queries.

Comment: @yiiframe `must use PDO (PHP data object) to avoid sql injection`. PDO doesn't inherently prevent SQL injection. You should suggest [binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to help prevent SQL injection. I say this because the way you have it at the moment, you could interpret as using [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) instead - which still allows SQL injection (providing no other data validation&sanitization).